# Brocade firmware update for ICX6450-48P switch

Tags: brocade

I just received some Brocade switches that are going to replace ancient Cisco ones on my network. The switches are running 07.4.00b of Brocade's firmware, and I'd like to know if it is safe to update to version 8. v8 just came out in June or July, so it would be useful to know if there are any gotchas - I'd hate to jump into buggy firmware with something as critical as a switch.

A comment about how the the latest stable v8 on a ICX 6450-48P runs would be great. I already know about the [1G reload bug](http://community.brocade.com/message/24352#24352).

Answer (score 0):

We've been happy with the router version of 8.0.10c firmware on a ICX6450-24 stack and two FCX stacks, running for the past six months.

Our only gotcha was the new default (OFF) for "redistribute connected" routes between versions 7 and 8.  We now must explicitly say "redistribute connected" in our "router" section to advertise the attached subnets..

The stacking behavior is even better than before...upgrade one stack member's firmware and the rest upgrade automatically.